# Using VS2013 Dev CMD: Compiling C# files to a different location?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cmd

I recently downloaded VS Community (since they just made it free), and am practicing compiling C# code. I figured out how to do it directly from VS (Ctrl + F5), and found out how to use csc.exe to compile they from the dev cmd, but how would one compile directly to the Desktop without doing two separate commands? I just want to be able to move the file to the Recycle Bin faster.

Comment: or hit 'Clean Solution'

Comment: Not sure what you trying to achieve ("want to be able to move the file to the Recycle Bin faster"), but csc.exe have built in help (csc /?) as well as detailed documentation on MSDN.

Comment: Note to close voter: Questions about programming tools are on-topic and should not be sent to SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when building from the command line you don't invoke `csc.exe` directly, you use MSBuild. MSBuild has a configuration parameter that allows you to specify the output directory.

```
MSBuild mysolution.sln /p:OutDir=C:\path\to\output\folder
```

This will build all of the projects in the solution and copy the output to the designated folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you build or run your code , visual studio creates debug/release folder in root directory of project.

But if you want to change this location to your desktop you can go to your project properties and from their you can change the debug output location.

See the attached image

[image]